# NSUserDefaults NSObject with NSArray Object

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I am trying to save object in `NSUserDefaults`, went throught many questions on this site but could not resolve the issue, my `NSObject` has an `NSMutableArray` of another object. like here the main object is `HotelDC` and it has an array "features" an array of `FeactureDC` objects.

Here is my code:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
self = [[HotelDC alloc] init];
if (self != nil) {

    self.hotel_id = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"hotel_id"];
    self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    self.features = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"features"];

}
return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

[encoder encodeInt:hotel_id forKey:@"hotel_id"];
[encoder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
[encoder encodeObject:features forKey:@"features"];//its a mutable array
}
```

how should I save it, and retrieve?? I am getting error as

```
 Attempt to insert non-property value '<HotelDC: 0xa600fe0>' of class 'HotelDC'. 
 Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
```

**Solution :**

```
//Setting
NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:hotelObjSelected];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:@"selectHotelObject"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// retrieving
NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"selectHotelObject"];
hotelObjSelected = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: HotelDC implements NSCoding, but what about FeatureDC?

Comment: @FirozeLafeer it also implements nscoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is backed by a property list. Alas, proprety lists cannot contain serialised objects. Quoting from [the manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData

You'll have to create your own serialised data file for saving the object directly, or serialise the objects as one of the allowed types. Annoyingly, `NSUserDefaults` doesn't call `encodeWithCoder` - it just screens the object type passed to `setObject:forKey:`. The best bet is to either serialise the fields of the `HotelDC` yourself, or archive the object to an `NSData` instance and store that.

Comment: As mentioned there NSArray, if i make my NSMutableArray to NSArray will it work?

Comment: It's not the `NSMutableArray` (as that's an `NSArray`, it would serialise). The problem is, at some point, you're calling `[nsUD setObject:someHotelDC forKey:aKey]`. `NSUserDefaults` is too stupid to call the `encodeObject` method - it just checks to see if the type of `someHotelDC` is a known property list type. It's not, so it throws the exception. You need to wrap up the `HotelDC` instance in a property list type before you try to add it to the property list (encoding as `NSData` first would work).

Answer (score 1):

I have did this by following way.check it. Below code is in for loop.

```
 NSMutableArray *newEventArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    [newEventArray addObject:title];
                    [newEventArray addObject:alarmDate];

 NSArray *iCalAlarmArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"alarmList"];
                    if(iCalAlarmArray == nil || [iCalAlarmArray count] <= 0)
                    {
                        iCalAlarmArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    }

iCalAlarmArray = [iCalAlarmArray arrayByAddingObject:newEventArray];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:iCalAlarmArray forKey:@"alarmList"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

May this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you should write similiar encoding and decoding methods in FeatureDC and store it in an array and then encode here.

Comment: yes i am doing the same encoding and decoding, u mean that i store object in an array and save that as NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:hotelObj];

Answer (score 0):

A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData